# google drive api - copyfile working only with permission for accessing all files in drive (but jst need to copy)

Tags: javascript, python, google-drive-api

We can copy using this page https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy.

But it is working only when I ask them permission https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive which means I can modify any file from his drive which is very bad. I just need to copy a public file to the authenticated user's account.

how can i do that?

When I am taking only this permission https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file, it is saying, the user has not granted write access to file  this file is the one that I am copying..

I am using application of type 'web' from api console.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy), Files.copy() requires at least one of the following three permissions:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`: "View and manage the files and documents in your Google Drive" which is the one you want to avoid

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`: "View and manage Google Drive files that you have opened or created with this app." Which means you can freely create any file but only open the files your app created. **You can only copy a file you created**, but you cannot copy any other files even if it is public.

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata`: "View and manage its own configuration data in your Google Drive" Which only lets you control your application-specific [Appdata folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata) which is probably not what you want. **You can only copy a file within appdata folder**, but again, no any other files even if user has permission to access it.

Long story short, you probably should use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope.